# Use python module on command line

Tags: python

I want to use python `re` on the command line, like

```
    $ python3 -m antigravity
    which open [xkcd: Python](https://xkcd.com/353/)
```

Then I tried `re`

```
    import -m re re.findall("\w+") < foo.md
    -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Is it possible to employ modules on the command line as `-m antigravity`

Comment: `antigravity` is written to do something when it's imported. `re` isn't. Also the error you're seeing is from your shell, not Python. If you want to run arbitrary Python and see the result of that (...which is a `TypeError`, in your case) try `python -c "import re; re.findall(r'\w+')"`.

Comment: Executing a module is different from executing python code that uses that module. If you want to run python code from the command line, use `python -c 'import re; print(re.findall(r"\w+"), input())'`.

Comment: `python -c "import re; re.findall(r'\w+')" < zen.md`
 `TypeError: findall() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`, not allow read from files @jonrsharpe

Comment: It's not clear what you expected it to do.

Comment: I expect to grab text from file `zen.md` @jonrsharpe  using regex

Comment: That's not going to happen. Just write a regular script. Not all modules are designed to be run like that.